# Cocoa/Objective C: methods and thread safety

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, thread-safety

In Cocoa/Objective C, are static class methods thread safe ?  I am defining a class to make related custom URL requests, that I would like to call from many different threads. Let's say I have a class:

```
@interface URLConnector : NSObject {
}
+(Response *)getData:(NSString *)category;
+(Response *)put:(NSString *)category content:(NSData *)content;
@end
```

Each method defines an NSMutableURLRequest, calls it, and uses NSRunLoop:runUntilDate: to wait for the response.  They also create instances of another class, URLConnectorDelegate to handle the callbacks from the NSMutableRequests, and release them before returning. (note: this code is based on a popular public library for making URL requests)

What I like about this approach is that it keeps all the threads simple and puts all the custom server-related code in one place.  The threads can execute URL requests with a single function call.

Can all of my threads use these static functions at once to make simultaneous calls (i.e. are static objective-c methods inherently thread-safe) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know you are going to be on a background thread why not just use `+[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:]` and be done with it?

No fuzz with the run-loop needed. And if you only use local variables and the arguments you get thread safety with barely any work at all.

Otherwise thread safety is up to you independently of method type.

Class methods are not any bit more thread safe than instance methods. Both kinds of methods are in fact treaded just the same by the run-time. The class is actually an object instance of it's meta-class, so a call to a class method is a normal method call to an object.

Comment: So, are both of these kinds of methods thread-safe as far as their local variables are concerned ?  For example, if I iterate over a local variable - for(int i=0; i<20; i++) - in the method, will this cause a conflict if two threads are running the method at the same time ?

Comment: @Colin: Any local variables on the stack are thread local and thus safe. So as long as you do not use variables marked as `static`, or are in any other way kept kept live outside the method's scope, you are safe.

Answer (score 3):

Being a class method has no influence one way or another on thread safety. What matters is how you access data. If you access data in ways that are not thread-safe, the method isn't thread-safe.

Rather than pumping your own run loop, I'd just attach the `NSURLConnection` to the main run loop and the URL loading system manage itself like it's designed to. See `NSURLConnection scheduleInRunLoop:forMode:`

Comment: I edited the question with a little more information about why I want to use this approach, though I take your point.  I've researched this topic on line a bit and some people report successfully running their own run loops this way, but may run into problems related to NSURLConnection itself.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any way you can do all the processing in the class methods without using instance variables that can get stomped on from various threads.  I think you need to make those methods normal instance methods and allocate an instance for each thread.  I'm not sure why you would even consider making them class methods in the first place.

Comment: I should have included that each time they are called, the static methods create a new connection delegate object to handle the responses.  I will edit the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are calling `NSRunLoop:runUntilDate:` for the current thread's run loop (i.e. whichever thread calls your class method), if there's no global/static variable being modified in these class methods, I believe they should be thread safe.